# Ubuntu Eclipse Version

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have a basic question, what is the latest version of Eclipse that is available for Ubuntu 9.04?

Comment: I recommend you to download latest version from eclipse.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version that is in the official repositories is 3.2.2,
[here's](https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/ppa) a PPA with version 3.4.1, and there's no reason why you can't download the latest version from [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads) if you want.

Answer (score 2):

[I want to say 3.2.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE)

Answer (score 1):

I just recently downloaded and installed Eclipse 3.4.2 Ganymede on my Ubuntu 9.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old article, but it still applies.  It goes through installing Ubuntu from eclipse.org

http://flurdy.com/docs/eclipse/install.html

It also talks about installing Tomcat, but you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a fairly recent version of Eclipse in the Ubuntu repositories. But if you want the cutting edge, [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68018/how-do-i-install-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1) has detailed instructions on how to extract eclipse into a directory (the preferred method on, say, Windows) and how to fix up all the links and shortcuts afterwards.

Personally, I prefer extracting eclipse to a user directory on Ubuntu, and this works fine for Eclipse 3.7.2